# Can javascript make a custom @rule of css?

Tags: javascript, css

CSS have rules like @media, @keyframes, etc. Can such be made using javascript, e.g. @myCustomRule. If yes then how ? If no then is there any alternative to that or just to go with CSS ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Those are called "at-rules".  No, you cannot make custom at-rules in JS.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule

Comment: You'd have to make your own pre-processor/pre-processing function that parses your stylesheet for your custom rule at compile time. The easiest way would be to create a webpack loader, or a function for whatever task runner you're using (if you're using one). When parsing, you'd have to replace your custom rule with native CSS that the browser can read.

Comment: Thats a great idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can't create your own custom @rules, you can use the [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model) to create supported rules and insert them into one of the browser's stylehseets with JavaScript:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const sheets = document.styleSheets;
  const lastStyleSheet = sheets[sheets.length - 1];
  const rule = `@keyframes rotate {
                  0%  {
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                  } 100% {
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                  }
                }`;

  lastStyleSheet.insertRule(rule, lastStyleSheet.rules.length);
  box.classList.add('rotate');
});
```

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#box.rotate {
  animation: rotate 100ms infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="button">Add Animation via JS</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that there is a way, well explained here:

[Defining Custom At-Rules in CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJsnUC72iII)

it uses [jsincss](https://github.com/tomhodgins/jsincss) and [jsincss-element-query](https://github.com/tomhodgins/jsincss-element-query)